# Constantly getting DuplicateKeyError with pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Pymongo was doing fine for weeks until I ran into the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "main.py", line 14, in 
        main()
      File "main.py", line 11, in main
        downloader.process()
      File "/mnt/vdisk/crawler/eurostat/downloader.py", line 25, in process
        self.processHelper()
      File "/mnt/vdisk/crawler/eurostat/downloader.py", line 61, in processHelper
        self.base.insert(documents)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 359, in insert
        continue_on_error, self.__uuid_subtype), safe)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 852, in _send_message
        rv = self.__check_response_to_last_error(response)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 793, in __check_response_to_last_error
        raise DuplicateKeyError(details["err"])
    pymongo.errors.DuplicateKeyError: E11000 duplicate key error index: test.eurostatdata.$_id_  dup key: { : ObjectId('50fd056757b924675af21a0e') }
```

_id was definitely not one of the field. I always rely on mongodb to generate its own _id, so I never had this kind of problem before.

code for insertion:

```
documents = []
for key in split_table_data:
    document = ele
    document["title"] = ele["title"]
    document["table_data"] = split_table_data[key]
    document["cols"] = colsHeader
    document["subTitles"] = key
    documents.append(document)
self.base.insert(documents)
```

I use the latest pymongo package and the latest mongodb.

The only thing that might have caused this would be that I tried to insert a document that was over the size limit.

I have tried

> db.repairDatabase()
>
> db.test.validate()

Comment: What is in the `ele` variable? I think this is your problem: `ele` variable already has _id key if it is obtained from from the DB.

Comment: Which version is this? 2.2.0?

Comment: ele does not have _id key because it was read in from an xml source. I have double checked that the _id key does not exist in ele

Comment: gregor, MongoDB is 2.2.0

Comment: Can you show your scheme document pls?